# How to make this polygon render as a complete shape rather than a crescent?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm using the following javascript function to create an array of vertices to pass to a buffer when creating a shape. It should calculate the vertices of an n-sided regular polygon with the first vertex located at the origin. The buffers are then created and stored as properties on the shape object that was passed to the function.

```
var vertices = [];

// Create each vertex by calculating the position of the new vertex relative
// to the old then adding on to the old position

// Begin by setting up the first vertex at the origin

vertices [0] = 0.0;
vertices [1] = 0.0;
vertices [2] = 0.0;

var oldX = 0.0;
var oldY = 0.0;

for (var i = 0; i < shape.numberOfSides; i++) {
    var theta = i * 2 * Math.PI / shape.numberOfSides;
    var y = shape.sideLength * Math.sin(theta);
    var x = shape.sideLength * Math.cos(theta);

    y += oldY;
    x += oldX;

    var start = (i+1) * 3;
    vertices [start] = x;
    vertices [start + 1] = y;
    vertices [start + 2] = 0.0;

    oldX = x;
    oldY = y;

}

// Create a buffer and store the vertices on it

shape.verticesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, shape.verticesBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

This works absolutely fine for triangles, but for pentagons or above the shape is not complete - it looks like a crescent. I've included a screenshot below of the working triangle and a non-working hexagon, both created with the same function.

http://i39.tinypic.com/ndoj8z.png

Can anyone see what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Start by drawing your polygon centered on the origin.  Then your vertices are simple functions of sin, cos, theta, and a value that is proportional to sideLength (you can use a variant of the Law of Cosines to find it).  Then, shift all the points over by that same proportion so that the first point is on the origin.

Comment: @Scott - Thank you for the idea! That would make it a lot simpler to work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw 1 trio of verticies and you should get an idea - Right now you're doing this:

```
(V1, V2, V3) -> Triangle along an edge
(V2, V3, V4) -> Another triangle along an edge.
(V3, V4, V5) -> Another triangle along an edge.
```

When you do that, no triangle ever passes through the center and you get the crescent you posted.

To draw it properly, you need to do this: (Fix 1 point of every triangle and move the other two points around the edge)

```
(V1, V2, V3)
(V1, V3, V4)
(V1, V4, V5)
```

This has an example image for reference : [Drawing GL Polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872464/opengl-es-how-to-draw-a-filled-polygon)