# Android OpenGL ES - How to draw a filled concave Polygon?

Tags: android, opengl-es, drawing, polygons

I am creating a 2D Openstreetmap rendering application for Android using OpenGL ES.

Unfortunately I am struggling with **drawing concave polygons** consisting of approximately **50 or more points**. In order to accomplish that my polygons are filled, I am using GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN:

```
gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff); // size = 2 because 2D

gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, pointCount, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuff);
```

**This approach works fine as long as my polygons are not too complex**, for example drawing a polygon like this is no problem at all:

[image]

My problem is, that GL_TRIANGLE_FAN always starts at the first point (a in this case) and then uses 2 other points to draw a triangle, until the whole shape is complete.

If a more complex polygon has to be drawn, this can lead to issues as you can see here:
(in this example, the **river that flows through the city is a complex polygon**)
[image]

My question now is how to avoid this problem so that even complex polygons are drawn **correctly and filled?**

The problem lies in drawing concave polygons.

When using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP instead of GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, the polygons are drawn, correctly, but only their points are connected together by triangles, the polygon itself is not filled.

Comment: GL_TRIANGLE_FAN can only reliably draw [*convex* polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are talking about OpenGL ES, it is much the same as the iOS issue here: [OpenGL ES - How to Draw a filled Polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872464/opengl-es-how-to-draw-a-filled-polygon)

In the above post, I've listed and tested 5 3rd party triangulation libs, but none of them is satisfying.

To conclude:

1. OpenGL ES doesn't have triangulation, thus does not support drawing filled concave polygon (not to mention polygon with holes...)
2. To Stick to OpenGL ES drawing, you have to find a 3rd party lib for triangulation (which is not easy...)
3. Use graphics.Paint(Android) / CoreGraphics(iOS) to draw filled path, but the performance is low

I've been looking for a light-weight and free triangulation lib for quite a long time, but...

Answer (score -4):

Not a great answer, but might help you reach a conclusion, take a look at convex hull generation:- http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html

Comment: A convex hull is a concave polygon, just thought it might send you along the right path :)

Comment: How is a [convex hull](https://www.google.com/search?q=convex+hull&tbm=isch) a concave anything? :|

Comment: a concave is something that curves inwards, so a convex hull does curve inwards, it curves around and is generally inwards...Too bad if my suggestion doesn't help you remotely. Have a great day